# Wifi completely missing from Laptop and can't connect to internet

Tags: network-adapter, wifi-driver

Asus Windows 10 Home version 10.0.17134

When I go to Settings-> Network & Internet, the WiFi section on the left side is completely missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Update Windows. You are using an old version from 3 years ago.
2. Update all drivers, especially network drivers. ASUS should have a Driver Update App. Do this.  Restart.
3. Open Control Panel, Device Manager and expand the network section. Is the Wireless Device there? Is there a red or yellow X beside it.

If the device is there, the above steps should bring it back.

If the device shows an error, there may be a hardware problem and then you need to get the machine serviced.

You can try a USB Ethernet or Wireless Card to substitute for a non-working internal card.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! 

I don't see any wireless network adopter device, it seems to be completely missing, does that mean that something is wrong with the hardware, which the only alternative would be a USB wireless card?

Comment: and there is no broken device under the network section.

Comment: Did you try all the steps I suggested?

Comment: You will likely need to use Ethernet to connect and do the work suggested.

Comment: I don't have an ethernet port on my laptop, that's the problem, is there another way to perform windows upgrade and the driver update through transferring files with USB Flash drive? or any other idea how to do it? thanks!

Comment: You need to get a USB card that has an Ethernet port - that may be easiest. Or try a USB Wireless card - make sure it has drivers.  You really need access to Internet to update the computer.

Comment: i c a usb port on my router, do you think usb to usb cable would also work?

Comment: You can try, but I am not sure if that would work. Better for a USB network card.

Comment: k, will get a USB network card and try to update. tnx.